# Change Page layout on a page programmatically SP13

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout

How can I change the page layout of a page.

i have tried this code but the page layout doesn't change.

```
      using (SPWeb web = newSiteCollection.OpenWeb())
        {
            string masterUrl = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(newSiteCollection.ServerRelativeUrl, "_catalogs/masterpage/MyCustomMstr.master");
            try
            {


                web.MasterUrl = masterUrl;
                web.CustomMasterUrl = masterUrl; 


                PageLayout layout = (from p1 in _web.GetAvailablePageLayouts()
                                      where p1.Name == "MyCustomPLayout.aspx"
                                      select p1).FirstOrDefault();
                SPFile file = web.GetFile("Sidor/default.aspx");
                var pu = PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage( file.GetListItem());
                pu.Layout = layout;

                file.Properties["vti_title"] = String.Empty;
                file.Properties["PublishingPageContent"] = String.Empty;

                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                web.Update();
            }
```

Comment: I have posted to your question on MSDN forum here: [link]https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/49a38398-f372-4c44-a117-857a1ce84961/chenga-pagelayout-programmaticlly-spweb-sp2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 1):

```
void SetDefaultPageLayout(string layoutName, SPWeb web)
{
    var pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
    if (pubWeb != null)
    {
        var pageLayout = pubWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts()
            .Single(pl => pl.Name == "MyCustomPLayout.aspx");
        pubWeb.SetDefaultPageLayout(pageLayout, true);
        pubWeb.Update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://aissp2013"))
{
    SPWeb rootWeb = site.RootWeb;
    PublishingWeb pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(rootWeb);
    PageLayout[] layouts = pubWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts();
    PageLayout layout = null;
    var matches = from l in layouts
                  where l.Name.Equals("ArticleLeft.aspx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                  select l;
    if (matches.Count<PageLayout>() > 0)
    {
        layout = matches.First<PageLayout>();
    }                     
    if (null != layout)
    {
        SPFile file = rootWeb.GetFile("/Pages/MyClients.aspx");
        if (PublishingPage.IsPublishingPage(file.Item))
        {
            PublishingPage page = PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage(file.Item);
            if (page.Layout != layout)
            {
                file.CheckOut();
                page.Layout = layout;
                page.Update();
                file.CheckIn("Changed layout");
                file.Publish("Initial Publish");                           
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/11/sharepoint-change-page-layout-through.html

Answer (score 0):

Please add the lines to check out and then check in the file. Also update the list item for which you are changing the page layout.

Answer (score 0):

Page layouts of a page can also be changed via `PowerShell` script. Here is a `CSOM PowerShell` function which will change the page layout.

Since its CSOM you need not run this on server, i.e. this can be executed from remote machine provide you have installed `SharePoint Client SDK`.

```
Try{
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll'
}

catch {
    Throw "Unable to load SharePoint Client runtime"
}

function ChangePageLayout()
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$siteurl,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$PageName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$PageLayoutName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$PageLayoutDisplayName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$Title,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][bool]$isCustomPageLayout
    )
    try
    {

        $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteurl)
        $ctx.Credentials = $credentials

        if($isCustomPageLayout -eq $false)
        {
            $PageLayoutName = "/_catalogs/masterpage/" + $PageLayoutName + "," + $PageLayoutDisplayName
        }
        else
        {
            #Here I have assumed that if its custom page layout, then it's placed inside some folder which is child to masterpage
            #If that's not the case with you then you can use below line of code
            #$PageLayoutName = "/_catalogs/masterpage/" + $PageLayoutName + ", " + $PageLayoutDisplayName
            #
            $PageLayoutName = "/_catalogs/masterpage/Custom Page Layouts/" + $PageLayoutName + ", " + $PageLayoutDisplayName
        }

        $Pages = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('Pages')
        $camlQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
        $camlQuery.ViewXml = '<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" /><Value Type="Text">'+ $PageName +'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>'
        $Page = $Pages.GetItems($camlQuery)
        $ctx.Load($Page)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        $file = $Page.File

        $ctx.Load($file)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        if ($file.CheckOutType  -ne [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CheckOutType]::None) {
            $file.UndoCheckOut()
            $ctx.Load($file)
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery() 
        }

        $file.CheckOut()
        $ctx.Load($file)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        $Page.Set_Item("PublishingPageLayout", $PageLayoutName)
        $Page.Set_Item("Title", $Title)
        $Page.Update()
        $Page.File.CheckIn("", [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CheckinType]::MajorCheckIn)
        $Page.File.Publish("")

        #check for approval
        $ctx.Load($Pages)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        if ($Pages.EnableModeration -eq $true) {
            $Page.File.Approve("")
        }

        $ctx.Load($Page)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        Write-Host "Update Page Layout Complete"
        Write-Host ""

    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host ("Error while changing page layout. Error -->> " + $_.Exception.Message) -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
$credentials = Get-Credential
ChangePageLayout "http:yoursite.com" $credentials "default.aspx" "YourCustomLayout.aspx" "Your Custom Page Layout" "Some Title" $true
```